# Show/Hide with a fade in animation after slidedown

Tags: jquery, animation, fadein, fadeout

I'm trying to add fadeIn/fadeOut animation after the slidedown here:

http://jsfiddle.net/lamberta/e44kB/

i tryed to add and write with 

`.fadeOut(350, function () {
&
.fadeOut(350, function () {`

But no work I can't figure out where to put it, someone know how place it here?

Comment: You want both slide and fade? Which first?

Comment: slidedown then fadeIn like the example under by @NullPointer

Comment: No one knows... still can't fix this

Comment: I'll help you out. Just give me a few to write up a new code for you to use. I'll give you a JSFiddle link (to view and test) and a PasteBin link (for full source code).

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by

[image: jsFiddle]

script

```
function toggleSlider() {
    if ($("#demo").is(":visible")) {
        $("#hola").animate(
            {
                opacity: "0"
            },
            600,
            function(){
                $("#hola").slideUp();
            }
        );
    }
    else {
        $("#demo").slideDown(600, function(){
            $("#hola").animate(
                {
                    opacity: "1"
                },
                600
            );
        });
    }   
}
```

html

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggleSlider();">toggle</a>
<div id="demo" style="display:none;background:#eee;padding:10px;">
    <div id="hola" style="opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0);">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ut tortor  erat, et consectetur nisl. Nunc non placerat odio. Cras feugiat  pulvinar diam sed sollicitudin. Quisque ut elit lacus, et gravida nunc.  Maecenas ac enim ligula. Aenean felis nunc, vulputate pellentesque  vehicula nec, tristique a tortor. Curabitur et semper dui. Sed id nisl  turpis. Sed vel nunc et nisi laoreet feugiat. Sed lobortis enim sed arcu  tempor vehicula. Vivamus dui ligula, ultricies id egestas ut, rhoncus  et est. Pellentesque dignissim diam vel nibh tempus condimentum. Etiam  sodales fermentum pharetra. Etiam faucibus tempus malesuada. Mauris  nulla lectus, laoreet sit amet cursus vel, ultricies at enim. Sed  facilisis rutrum eros, nec malesuada eros iaculis ac.

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes exactly the effect im trying to get but this one is only work once? I press one time and it stops working and the linking not working like/with the old code. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/lamberta/AwsRZ/